# Use Red FR-15 or Park FR-5.2 to remove a Shimano cassette?

Tags: cassette, tools

I'm planning to grease the bearing and have a freewheel system based on Shimano Deore. Can someone tell me which tool to get to remove the sprockets? The back wheel has a threaded through axle.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles Exchange.  Can you add additional detail to your question so that we can answer it?  Details like how many cogs (speeds) on the cassette, does your hub use a quick release or a thru-axle to mount it, what specific cassette is it (what group set, i.e., Ultegra, 105, etc.) is it?  These details will help get you to the correct answer to your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some terminology issues that make it a bit unclear what you are trying to do after removing the cassette. Additionally, a freewheel is a completely different system from cassettes. Freewheels have a ratcheting mechanism inside. Cassettes have no ratcheting mechanism. They slide onto a splined interface on the hub called the *freehub body*, so I wonder if you meant to refer to that item.

Focusing just on the question at hand: either tool should work fine! The Park FR-5.2 is a tool for Shimano lockrings. The Red Cycling Products FR-15 appears to be the same sort of tool. Now, at minimum, you will need to use an adjustable wrench to hold the tool *and* you will need a chain whip (or similar device).

In the former's case, most adjustable wrenches don't offer that much leverage for this use case, so there are more specialist cassette tools available with longer levers. You can get the cassette off, but it takes a lot of effort - I just did this on my bike. In the latter case, you can't unscrew the lockring without holding the cassette cogs in place (lay people might call these the *gears*), because the freehub will go into freewheel mode. Thus, you need a tool like the Park Tools SR-18.2. Park might make one or more higher end models of that tool, and other manufacturers will make their own versions.

What do you lose from going to a cheaper tool? Tolerances and materials are two areas where manufacturers can compromise to reduce costs. Cheaper materials might not make much of a difference here, especially not for something a consumer might use occasionally. Nevertheless, if the steel is soft, you could imagine that workshop use might cause the tool to deform over time. For tolerances, a tool with too loose tolerances might fit too loosely in the splines, or it might fit too tight. Chances are you can't go wrong with Park Tools, and for some items you do not want to cheap out, but a cassette tool and chain whip are probably fine.

---

The paragraphs below were written before the OP clarified that they have a Shimano Deore hub, which has cup and cone bearings. I'm leaving them for posterity, but cup and cone bearings definitely need periodic servicing. Cartridge bearings don't.

Now, it's unclear what you mean by "grease the bearing". There are two bearings in the rear hub, and there should be another one or two bearings in the freehub. You will frequently need additional steps to remove the freehub body, but most hubs should just need Allen wrenches. Cup and cone hubs often need a spanner to hold the locking nuts in place, and an adjustable wrench might be too big to grip the flats on the nuts. So, you will need to consider this. Then, if you have cartridge bearings with rubber seals, you don't actually need to service those bearings. Cartridge bearings are in most hubs (aside from Shimano hubs), and they are designed to be run until they fail, and then you would pull them out and replace them entirely.

Cup and cone bearings, which are in most (or all current?) Shimano hubs do indeed need to be greased periodically. Annually is probably enough). I forget what the bearing arrangement in Shimano freehubs is, but I think there's one set of bearings on the non-drive side, and one more in the freehub body. If you want to go through with this, just investigate the internal arrangement of the hub first.

Comment: Shimano rear hubs with loose ball bearings have a ring of 9, 1/4 inch balls on each side. The right, drive side is located toward the end of the free hub body. The bearing cup is what closes off the internals of the freehub body. The left, non drive side of the hub houses the bearing balls and cup underneath various designs of dust seals, aspects of which are often part of the cone nut.  Typically, one will work on the left side, separating the lock nut from the cone nut, then removing both from the axle. The axle, with the right side hardware in place, can be removed out the right side.

Comment: To be clear, there are additional bearings within the freehub body.  Interestingly, the inner aspect of the drive side cup mentioned above, is the cone for one level of bearings within the freehub body.  The internals of a Shimano freehub body are not intended to be serviced. One simply replaces the body. The axle bearings (the external, 1/4 inch balls, conenut, etc.) DO need at least yearly service: remove, clean and regrease. Inspect and replace worn or damaged parts, with the bearing balls being the the first and most frequent aspect of replacement